# Post Heresy Corax story where he hunts down Primarchs and nearly wins a fight against Lorgar

Tags: story-identification, warhammer-40k

I have read in various places online that in the 41st millennia Corax is still alive hunting down the traitor Primarchs in the Eye of Terror. A fight against Lorgar is mentioned, which Corax nearly won. However nothing I can find is referenced so I can’t go to the original source material that describes this.

Can someone point me to the novel/short story, or is it something mentioned in a source or rule book, published by Games Workshop/The Black Library as opposed to wiki type pages that don’t reference where this info is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear to be ["Shadows of the Past"](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Past_(Anthology_Short_Story)) (2018), published by The Black Library in the [*Sons of the Emperor*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38450891-sons-of-the-emperor) anthology.

From the Reddit thread ["So we have an answer on what has become of Corvus Corax apparently (Spoilers)"](https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/8y7dgg/so_we_have_an_answer_on_what_has_become_of_corvus/):

> Corax went on to hunt the traitor Primarchs, seeking revenge for the Drop Site Massacre. At some point he became mutated by the powers of the Warp, turning into a creature made of darkness and shadow itself. Using his new abilities, Corax wreaked havoc on a Word Bearers Daemon World in the Eye of Terror. Far beyond the abilities of average Word Bearers, the Daemon Primarch Lorgar himself appeared before Corax and the two engaged in a vicious duel. Corax managed to dominate the battle, forcing Lorgar to retreat and close the portal he had arrived from. As Lorgar vanished, Corax vowed that he would hunt down and slay the Daemon Primarch.
>
> Source: Sons of the Emperor (Anthology) - Shadows of the Past

---

Found with the Google Query `40k corax hunting primarch alive`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: when does it take place? Both Lorgar and Corax have been unheard of for a long time. Also, isn't there a prophecy saying that the Corax will kill Lorgar (in the "First Heretic" they fight briefly even after Lorgar hears that "you know, that he will kill you" warning).

Comment: @Yasskier I'll be honest... I have absolutely no idea :D I really don't know much about 40k, the above answer was just an ID one as it seemed to fit OP's description. Hopefully RichardC knows way more about that than I do and will be able to answer :)

Comment: This is why it intrigued me, from the looks of it it is set in the 41st millenia, seeing as how GW have started to bring primarchs back I imagine it is possible that Lorgar and Corax may be the next 2 to return.